# Lista en orden alfabetice con angularjs, donde el primer valor por letra esta prefijado

Tags: html, css, angularjs

estoy queriendo realizar un listado ordenado alfabéticamente, con la característica de que por cada letra coloque una especia de titulo, que también esta incluido en la lista principal. Doy un ejemplo simple para reflejar mi problemática.
La lista principal seria algo así.

```
$scope.Lista = 'Benjamin'
$scope.Lista = 'Cordoba'
$scope.Lista = 'Cristiano'
$scope.Lista = 'Alberto'
$scope.Lista = 'Andres'
$scope.Lista = 'Bruno'
$scope.Lista = 'Carlos'
$scope.Lista = 'Nombres con A'
$scope.Lista = 'Nombres con C'
$scope.Lista = 'Nombre con B'
```

Lo que necesito hacer, es que cuando haga el order:

```
<tr ng-repeat="elem in $ctrl.Lista | orderBy:elem >
```

La lista resultado me quede de la siguiente forma:

```
Nombres con A
Alberto
Andres
Nombre con B
Benjamin
Bruno
Nombres con C
Carlos
Cordoba
Cristiano
```

y a su vez necesito que si hago un filtro por letras, por ejemplo A, me muestre todos los nombre que comiencen con A y a su vez el titulo.

```
 Nombres con A
 Alberto
 Andres
```

En un inicio se me ocurrió generar una lista aparte insertandole los "títulos" en el lugar que tendrían que ir, pero luego pensando que también tengo que agregar el filtro se me cayo la idea. 
Agradecería mucho que me dieran alguna recomendación. Desde ya les doy gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Hola Hugo. Usar un pipe para ordenar una lista esta catalogado como mala practica. Es mejor que los ordenes en una función externa que retorne un arreglo ordenado. En mi opinión y para fines de orden, yo crearía un diccionario con cada letra y dentro anidaría otro con los nombres. `ctrl.Lista['a']=['angel', ...]`. Lo mostraría con dos ng-repeat anidados. El primero que obtenga las claves con `Object.keys` y el segundo seria directamente.

Comment: Angel. Te agradezco por el consejo, voy a probar realizándolo como comentas. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución es primero determinar que grupos vamos a buscar, luego, a partir de esos grupos buscar los que coincidan y ordenarlos:

```js
const lista = ['Benjamin', 'Cordoba', 'Cristiano', 'Alberto', 'Andres', 'Bruno', 'Carlos', 'Nombres con A', 'Nombres con C', 'Nombres con B'];

const titulos = lista.filter(e => e.includes("Nombres con"));

const res = titulos.map(t => {
  return [t, ...lista.
    filter(n => n[0] === t.replace(/Nombres con /, "")).
    sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
  ]

}).flat();


console.log(res);
```

Esta solución dejaría afuera los que no tienen grupo, además los caracteres especiales no se ordenan perfectamente con este método, se podría usar algo como `b.localeCompare(a, 'es', {sensitivity: 'base'}))`